# Setup sharing of a directory on Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I have a number of public notebooks with addresses like

- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/lyapunov.nb
- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/util.nb
- etc

Is there a way to setup sharing of the whole directory?

- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/

Right now it gives
[image]

Answer (score 6):

We don't have a way to set up an *automatic* index page yet. But if there is a cloud object `index.html` or `index.nb` in the directory, it will be served as the index page for the directory (as long as the viewer has permission to that object). This could be a static page (including a notebook), or it could be generated dynamically.

E.g. the following code deploys a `Delayed` object that serves a simple (HTML) index page for the cloud directory `testdir`:

```
getItem[CloudObject[url_, ___]] := 
 ExportString[
  XMLElement[
   "li", {}, {XMLElement["a", {"href" -> url}, {FileNameTake[url]}]}],
   "XML"]

getIndexPage[obj_CloudObject] := 
 StringJoin[
  "<html><head><title>Directory Index</title></head><body><ul>", 
  getItem /@ CloudObjects[obj], "</ul></body></html>"]

CloudDeploy[
 Delayed[getIndexPage[
   ParentDirectory[
    CloudObject[$EvaluationCloudObject, 
     CloudObjectNameFormat -> "CloudUserUUID"]]], "HTML"], 
 CloudObject["testdir/index.html"]]
```

Note the use of `CloudObjectNameFormat` so that the `$EvaluationCloudObject` is considered in its named form, making sure that `ParentDirectory` does the right thing.

Use the option `Permissions->"Public"` (or `CloudPublish` instead of `CloudDeploy`) if you want to make the index page public.

In the future, we'll make this configurable using a `CloudObject` option on the directory itself. Perhaps it will be something like `DirectoryIndexObject`, where the default `Automatic` would look for `index.html` or `index.nb` as it does now, and would serve an automatically generated index page if they don't exist – as long as the requester has Read permission on the directory.